# rating control for cocoa (Mac OS)

Tags: macos, cocoa, rating

Do you know a good cocoa rating control?
It is for Mac OS, not iOS.
Expected features:
- From 0 to 5 stars
- idealy binding support

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with a Simple 5 star rating control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246126/help-with-a-simple-5-star-rating-control)

Answer (score 2):

[NSLevelIndicator](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLevelIndicator_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will do this when its cells are set to use `NSRatingLevelIndicatorStyle`.